# If the sum and the product of two sequences converges to zero, does that mean that each sequence converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the sum and the product of two sequences converges to zero, 
does that mean that each sequence converges to zero ?

Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts? What sequences have you tried?

Comment: I think he's asking if $$a_n+b_n\to 0 \land a_n b_n\to 0\implies a_n\to 0\land b_n\to 0$$ is true.

Comment: It seems a nice question. Why no upvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Fill in the details.)

1. Prove that if $|a_n + b_n | \leq \epsilon$ and $|a_n b_n | \leq \epsilon^2$, then $|a_n - b_n| \leq \sqrt{5} \epsilon$.
   Use the fact that $(a_n - b_n)^2 = (a_n+b_n)^2 - 4 a_n b_n$.
2. Hence conclude that $|a_n| \leq \frac{1 + \sqrt{5} }{2} \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n+b_n=:s_n$, $\ a_n b_n=:p_n$. Then $a_n$, $b_n$ are the two solutions of  the quadratic equation $x^2-s_n x+p_n=0$. It follows that
$$\max\bigl\{|a_n|,|b_n|\bigr\}={1\over2}\left(|s_n|+\sqrt{s_n^2-4p_n}\right)\to0\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n \not\to 0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad\exists\varepsilon>0, \exists n_k\ (n_k<n_{k+1}),\ |a_{n_k}| > \varepsilon \quad \Longrightarrow \quad b_{n_k} = \frac{a_{n_k}b_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}} \to 0,\ k \to \infty \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_{n_k} = (a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}) - b_{n_k} \to 0,\ k \to \infty.$$
Contradiction.

*ADDED.*
**Second solution.**
If $a_nb_n \to 0$ then $a_n\overline{b_n} \to 0$ and $\overline{a_n}b_n \to 0$. Hence
$$|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2 = (a_n+b_n)(\overline{a_n+b_n}) - a_n\overline{b_n} - \overline{a_n}b_n \to 0.$$

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: Which part? ${}$

Comment: None, now that you edited your answer...:)

Comment: OK. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n),(b_n)$ be your sequences. Then $a_n+b_n,a_nb_n\to0$, so $(a_n+b_n)^2-2a_nb_n=a_n^2+b_n^2\to0$. Since $0\leq a_n^2,b_n^2\leq a_n^2+b_n^2$, it follows that both $a_n^2$ and $b_n^2$ converge to $0$, so the same happen to $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: This applies only to real-valued sequences.